# Open a window with javascript, and have the HTML content loaded from an external source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I am new to HTML/Javascript

I want to open a window with javascript, and have it's HTML content loaded from an external source. 
I used document.write() but it does not work unless I specifically write the HTML as a parameter

Any idea how to let document.write read from an external source?

Here is what I tried.

```
win.document.write('<script src="window.html"></script>');
```

window.html

```
  <html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        test
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want to write the content this way, rather than just point the new window at a url?  `window.open("window.html");`

Comment: I think you might be interested in the `iframe` element.

Comment: it worked. I will update my post above. If there are better solution then please tell me

Comment: There's examples of use **[on this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open)** but you need to be looking at setting width and height in the `window.open` options.  Also, have you considered a dialog, instead of a different window?  http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get another page into a new window, then just pass the URL when you create the window...

```
window.open('win.html', 'popup1', 'width=400,height=200,toolbar=0,location=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=0,resizable=0');
```

You may also want to consider using a [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/), purely for presentation purposes :)

Answer (score 1):

Document.write is not the right way.

1) Add jquery.js to your head document.

2) In the header add also this code

```
<script>
//document ready
$(function(){
   var newDiv = $('<div></div>');
   newDiv.load('window.html');
   //now you have the window.html in the div content
   $('body').append(newDiv);
});

or

//Open in new window
$(function(){
  window.open('window.html');
});


or


//Open in iframe

var iframe = $('<iframe></iframe>');
iframe.attr('src','window.html');
$('body').append(iframe);

</script>
```

You must set the size of the div and the iframe.

Comment: Why you remove jquery tag??